# How to figure out which port a programe is using in linux?

Tags: linux, port

```
memcached -u www-data -m 2048 -d
```

After I run the above,I've no idea which port it's using ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default port is 11211

```
lsof|grep -E '^memcached.*LISTEN'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use netstat -lp

-l is short form of --listening and -p is short form of --program

For example, to list programs listening on TCP ports (-t or --tcp) and show ports and IPs numerically (-n or --numeric):

$ netstat -nltp

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      995/mysqld      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1350/memcached
```